# Making sure the goal state is reachable/clearing it when planning with MoveIt!

Tags: ros, moveit, octomap, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When planning using MoveIt!, it sometimes happens that a intended goal state cannot be reached because it is close to a collision and noise in sensor data (e.g. octomap) leads to collision checks failing, meaning planning is aborted. Are there already mechanisms in place for avoiding this issue, for example just clearing the goal state?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62113/making-sure-the-goal-state-is-reachable/clearing-it-when-planning-with-moveit!/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Stefan,

Could you please ask future MoveIt! related questions on the moveit-users mailing list: moveit-users@googlegroups.com. Its easier for us to track MoveIt! specific questions there.

It would be unsafe for us to clear a goal state like you suggested - how do we know whether that's an actual obstacle or something that comes from noise? We are working on alternatives that would let you plan away from contact positions or towards contact positions, but this will take some time and won't be available immediately.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1